# Multiple table join dilema

Tags: sql

Let say we have following set of joins performed:

A -> B -> C -> D

This set of joins produces only one 1 row in a result set.
Now if we add more joins:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
     | 
     E -> F -> G
```

Now B is joined also with E.

All joins are inner joins.

Can we guarantee that resulting set will have always 0 or 1 row?

Comment: This is a somewhat atypical diagram to describe a SQL query.  Can you provide some data, ideally a minimal sample demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: No. If any of the joins B -> E, E->F, F->G are one-to-many then you can potentially get more than one row back from your query.

Comment: One-to-many relationship depends on the columns used for the join. Having a UK or PK on both side ensure a one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you want to ensure a 0 or 1 row you have to ensure that every table join on their primary key or a unique index on both side; also your WHERE clause ensure one table return 0 or 1 row.

It's important to be unique index or primary key because every JOIN ensure multiplicity. Having unique index or primary key ensure a (0,1)x(0,1) relationship.